# Как из мобильной версии сайта сделать приложение для ios?

Tags: ios, android, java, xcode, objective-c

Есть мобильная версия сайта. Нужно сделать приложения для ios.

Приложение должно быть полностью идентичным мобильному сайту, так что смысла делать приложение с нуля не вижу. Можно ли сделать вставку мобильного сайта в приложение (чтобы отображалось как в браузере, но без элементов интерфейса самого браузера, только сайт) и не противоречит ли это правилам app store?

P.S. Интересует также, как реализовать и для android.

Comment: WebView. Это можно сделать, используя WebView. Но если вы этого не знаете, значит вы с iOS разработкой не знакомы, соответственно сами сделать этого не сможете.

Comment: @rumbex, Согласно правилам форума, вопросы не должны сводиться к решению либо завершению учебных заданий за учащихся. Пожалуйста, уточните, что вы сделали сами и что не получилось.

Comment: Возьмите в руки устройство, откройте мобильную версию вашего сайта.

Что не нравится - записываем. Если что-то записали - делаем приложение с исправлениями. Все.

А съесть рыбку и одновременно... забор чтоб покрасился - не получится.

Answer (score 2):

> Нужно сделать приложения для ios.
>
> Приложение должно быть полностью идентичным мобильному сайту
>
> смысла делать приложение с нуля не вижу.

Я не знаю, как отвечать на такие вопросы, поэтому:

```
NSString *fullURL = @"http://hashcode.ru/"; //вы же понимаете о чем я..
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:fullURL];
NSURLRequest *requestObj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
[webView loadRequest:requestObj];
```

я просто не могу понять.

Если есть мобильная версия и от нее не должно отличаться, то зачем делать приложение?!

Как добавить webView, я могу написать, но тогда ваш вопрос могут удалить по правилам ресурса, за полученное решение. Почитайте, кстати.

Comment: кстати, в App Store эту фигню зареджектят на раз, с описанием как слишком простое. Т.е. или делать нормальное приложение, или это и так видно в браузере.

Answer (score 1):

> кстати, в App Store эту фигню
> зареджектят на раз, с описанием как
> слишком простое. Т.е. или делать
> нормальное приложение, или это и так
> видно в браузере.

Полностью согласен с автором комментария. Такое не пропустят в аппстор. Приложение нужно писать с нуля. Единственное, что есть, - графика и дизайн + вы знаете, куда будут осуществляться переходы по ссылкам. Но графику, скорее всего, нужно будет перерисовать для поддержки ретины экранов. Также приложение должно быть универсальным, не только айфон, но и айпад. Исходя из изложенного:

- перерисовка графика с поддержкой ретины-экранов;
- скорее всего, парсинг хтмл-сайта (у вас же не будет приложение состоять из одних WebView);
- возможно, понадобятся АПИ-запросы к сайту, типа на регистрацию, комменты и т.д.;
- поддержка айфона и айпада.

И это основное, что нужно, дальше мелочь, которая решается уже на месте.

Answer (score 0):

[Вот это можно попробовать.](http://phonegap.com/)